# Creating own class for urlManager

Tags: yii

These are my rules for urlManager. It works only for controller 'vijesti'. When I try to open any other page it gives me 404 error.
Should I write my own class for urls or what? Could someone explain me what to do?

```
'<controller:(vijesti)>/<action:(admin|create|update|delete|trazi)>' => 'vijesti/<action>',
'<kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+>'=>'vijesti/view',            
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: Can you show description of 404 error? Are you assured that asked controller and action are exists?

Comment: It says 404 requested page does not exist. When I remove my rules it works. Every page is functional when I remove my rules

Comment: I need description of error for helping you

Comment: That's all it says, even with yii debug turned on

Comment: You need turn on logging. See how [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging), you need route `CWebLogRoute`

Comment: what is it going to tell me?

Comment: It's tell you what kind of problem with your rules. Maybe you forgotten parameter `$id` in `actionView` (if using rule `'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view'`) or you don't have controller or action, or other... For solving problem need more information, because you rule is fine in first look

Comment: http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/6312/n47d.jpg
here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:

the rule `'<kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+>'=>'vijesti/view'` covers `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'`

Try this:

```
'<controller:(vijesti)>/<action:(admin|create|update|delete|trazi)>' => 'vijesti/<action>',
'/<kategorija:\w+>/vw_<naslov:\w+>'=>'vijesti/view',            
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: that works but because of this '/kategorija/naslov'=>'vijesti/view',  I have no the url I wanted (SEO url).

Now it is: /kategorija/naslov?naslov=9plkd6AKGF&kategorija=hrvatska

Comment: Explain purpose of this rule `'<kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+>'=>'vijesti/view',`

Comment: When user tries to open vijesti/view page it should be like www.mysite.com/politics/jh8fFhk  => politics is category and jh8ffhk is random string I have in my database something like ID to identify article. vijesti=news, kategorija=category

Comment: If I make it like this '<kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+>/<action:(view)>'=>'vijesti/<action>', then everything works, but it is not desired url, it includes "view" in my link

Comment: As for me better: `'/view/<kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+>' => >'vijesti/view'` for viewing category by hash. But your problem is cannot loading model `profile` on `VijestiController` in line 77

Comment: point is I have to use some static string in front of <kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+> for link to work, I didn't know that. But it is not good, if I specified that regex only for vijesti/view, it should't try to find match in <kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+> for other urls

Comment: how about url `www.mysite.com/politics/vw_jh8fFhk`? here is the rule for such url: `/<kategorija:\w+>/vw_<naslov:\w+>`

Comment: that is great too, thanks for your help :D
TOday I've learned something new about yii :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
'vijesti/<_a:(admin|create|update|delete|trazi|view)>' => 'vijesti/<_a>',
'<kategorija:\w+>/<naslov:\w+>'=>'vijesti/view',            
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: by the way, if you don't need to handle incoming urls, you don't have to create a custom url class.

Comment: I tried that also it doesn't work, like it only recognizes controller 'vijesti' and none other